# What is M73 Q17 S43 G-code command?

Tags: marlin, g-code, slic3r, prusa-research

I know that `M73 P19` means "Set completion progress to 19%", and I suspect that `M73 R42` means "Set remaining time to 42 minutes", but what is `M73 Q17 S43`? I can't find description of such syntax.

The command is seen in `.gcode` files produced by PrusaSlicer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`M73` Set/Get build percentage G-code](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M73:_Set.2FGet_build_percentage) is only defined for a selected few printer firmwares.

As you suspected, next to `M73 P19` (tell the firmware at what completage percentage the print is) the `M73 R42` tells the firmware the left time to completion.

If you look at the description of the [`M73` G-code](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M73:_Set.2FGet_build_percentage), the following parameters may be used:

- `P`: Percent in normal mode
- `R`: Time remaining in normal mode
- `Q`: Percent in silent mode
- `S`: Time remaining in silent mode

So, running the `Q` and `S` parameters, is similar to the `P` and `R` parameters with the exception for referring to the printer percentage/time when in stealth (quiet) mode.

These modes, normal and stealth, [refer to power modes of Prusa printers](https://help.prusa3d.com/article/8LLgVlD01q-loud-printer):

> **Normal vs. Stealth mode**
>   MK3 printers offer two print modes. Normal mode is required for the detection of lost steps (shifted layers), while still being quieter than the silent mode on MK2/S. There is also the Stealth mode, which utilizes Trinamic StealthChop technology, making the printer almost inaudible with the print cooling fan being the noisiest part of the printer. However, Stealth mode does not provide lost step detection.

Stealth mode times can be a bit higher than normal mode estimation times. Estimation is done by the slicer. As Prusa maintains this feature, their times are accurate for their printers, but that does not have to be the case for custom printers.

To get the current progress, the `M73` command is called without parameters:

> Use "M73" by itself to get a report of the current print progress.

Comment: Saw your answer too late :( I have already found this in MK3S firmware source.

Comment: @Alex No problem, now it's out there for others to read too! Happy printing! :)

Answer (score 2):

The tooltip for "Supports remaining times" under `Printer Settings -> General -> Firmware`in PrusaSlicer quotes:

```
Emit M73 P[percent printed] R[remaining time in minutes] at 1 minute intervals
into the G-code to let the firmware show accurate remaining time.
As of now only the Prusa i3 MK3 firmware recognizes M73.
Also the i3 MK3 firmware supports M73 Qxx Sxx for the silent mode.
```

Therefore:

- P = Percentage printed, normal mode
- R = Remaining time, normal mode
- Q = Percentage printed, silent mode
- S = Remaining time, silent mode